# How to make the content in your canvas responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, typescript

Hi I was trying to get the values out of the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" property="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I found to get content out of a meta tag with js:

```js
function getVieuwContent() {
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');

    for (let i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
        if (metas[i].getAttribute("property") == "viewport") {
            return metas[i].getAttribute("content");
        }
    }

    return "";
}

console.log(getVieuwContent());
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" property="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I just get `width-device-width, initial-scale=1` printed in my console.
While I hoped that I got from a number from it. I want to make the content in the canvas responsive like css is responsive from the meta tag on mobile.

What I have now:

- Full screen

  - Auto updates canvas width when the `window.innerWidth` changes
  - Auto updates canvas height when the `window.innerHeight` changes
  - css `{ position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; }`
- A centered rectangle *(the content that needs to be responsive)*

Working snippet:

```js
function getId(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

const canvas = getId('canvas');
canvas.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const requestAnimation = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimation;

class Rectangle {
  constructor(x = 0, y = 0, w = 5, h = 5, color = '#0ff') {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = color;
  }

  Update(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }

  Draw(cvs) {
    let ctx = cvs.ctx;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(
        //centers the width of the rectangle
        this.x - this.w / 2,
        //centers the height of the rectangle
        this.y - this.h / 2,
        this.w,
        this.h);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

let rect;

function SetUp() {
  Start();
  Update();
}

function Start() {
  rect = new Rectangle(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 100, 100)
}

function Update() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  rect.Update(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 100, 100)
  rect.Draw(canvas);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(Update);
}

SetUp();
```

```css
#canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you mean "make the content in your canvas responsive"? If you're rendering things to a canvas, that's all dependent on you; that's kind of the point of using a canvas.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to read the width of the window?

document.body.offsetWidth will work in a decent browser

Comment: If I make an object the size is by pixels. My laptop is 1600x900 pixels and my phone is 1920x1080 pixels. the size of my object is differently on my laptop and phone. but to the eye I want the same size.

Comment: @R.Walstijn Then you need to perform your own scaling relative to the screen resolution. Since *you* handle the rendering in a canvas, *you* are responsible for sizing it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have found that you should make a calculation of the width and height.

So that the **content** is responsive in the canvas.
See the link for the end result:

```js
function getId(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

const canvasA = getId('canvasA');
canvasA.ctx = canvasA.getContext("2d");

const canvasB = getId('canvasB');
canvasB.ctx = canvasB.getContext("2d");

const canvasC = getId('canvasC');
canvasC.ctx = canvasC.getContext("2d");

const requestAnimation = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimation;

class Rectangle {
  constructor(x = 0, y = 0, w = 5, h = 5, color = '#0ff') {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.color = color;
  }

  Update(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }

  Draw(cvs) {
    let ctx = cvs.ctx;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(
        //centers the width of the rectangle
        this.x - this.w / 2,
        //centers the height of the rectangle
        this.y - this.h / 2,
        this.w,
        this.h);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

let rect,
  fragmentA,
  fragmentB,
  fragmentC;

function SetUp() {
  Start();
  Update();
}

function Start() {
  rect = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100);
}

function Update() {
  canvasA.width = window.innerWidth * 0.9;
  canvasA.height = 200;
  canvasB.width = window.innerWidth * 0.5;
  canvasB.height = 200;
  canvasC.width = window.innerWidth * 0.4;
  canvasC.height = 200;
  
  // Getting 1/10 of the width
  fragmentA = canvasA.width * 0.1;
  fragmentB = canvasB.width * 0.1;
  fragmentC = canvasC.width * 0.1;

  rect.Update(canvasA.width / 2, canvasA.height / 2, fragmentA * 2, fragmentA * 2)
  rect.Draw(canvasA);
  
  rect.Update(canvasB.width / 2, canvasB.height / 2, fragmentB * 2, fragmentB * 2)
  rect.Draw(canvasB);
  
  rect.Update(canvasC.width / 2, canvasC.height / 2, fragmentC * 2, fragmentC * 2)
  rect.Draw(canvasC);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(Update);
}

SetUp();
```

```css
canvas {
  margin: -4px -5px;
  border-style: solid;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvasA'></canvas>
<canvas id='canvasB'></canvas>
<canvas id='canvasC'></canvas>
```